# Enforce srun to use exclusive cores on a single socket

Tags: slurm

I'm using `sbatch` and I have a node with 2 sockets, each having 18 cores, totalling 36 cores. I'm launching 4 scripts where each has two tasks that share a GPU:

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=2                  
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
```

Such configuration run 4 times gives 4 x 2 x 4 = 32 allocated cores. How to make sure every distinct job has exclusive cpus allocated only within a single socket? In other words, there cannot be a situation where job is allocated e.g. CPUs 0, 1, 22, 33 since they are placed on two different sockets, and each job should have exactly 4 cpus available when looking at cpu-bind.

Of course I could somehow play with cpu masks but the problem is that node configuration and number of jobs varies and I don't want to do it for every configuration.

I was looking at `--cpu-bind=sockets` but it seems it does not allocate exclusive processors:

```
cpu-bind=MASK - mycomp, task  0  0 [83008]: mask 0xff set
cpu-bind=MASK - mycomp, task  1  1 [83009]: mask 0xff set
```

Answer (score 1):

Slurm allows for a more detailed processor bindings. The `sbatch` script preamble should contain your desired configuration:

```
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-socket=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
```

Processor affinity can be further refined with additional arguments to `srun` (similar options exist for `mpirun`):

```
srun --extra-node-info=2:2:1 --cpu-bind=cores my_executable
```

- `extra-node-info` specifies the socket:core:thread distribution and has precedence over the above 3 directives
- `cpu-bind=cores` tells `srun` to bind the processes to cores

Comment: Unfortunately, `--extra-node-info / -B` only act as minimum values. Its not possible to restrict oneself to a single socket with this. It can still happen, that the scheduler assigns 16 CPUs across 2 sockets, even though `-B 1:8:2` was specified.